# Make an ODE more easily solvable by a substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For this Ordinary Differential Equation
$$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 3x\frac{dy}{dx}  + 3y = 9\ln(x)$$

How can I show that,

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + x\frac{dy}{dx}  $$

using the substitution  $x = e^t$

So that, I can solve the ODE easily in the form $$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} - 4\frac{dy}{dt}  + 3y = 9t$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the chain rule

$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} = e^t\frac{dy}{dx} = x\frac{dy}{dx} $$

Repeat for the second derivative
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right) \frac{dx}{dt} = \dots $$

I assume you can take it from here